# Excel Vba Regular Expression Not Detecting

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have tried to detect the same on regex101, but when I try to run the excel-VBA code it fails to detect.

I have been trying to detect and group the Following Text:

```
Test A1 (III’15) 270     10/12  ABC/DEF       PNR       AVC
Test Asd(II’05) 300     11/12  RtF/ZXC      PNR        NKL
Test 33 (I’01) PIL     11/12  KNP/ILO      IL 90.5    FX - NO
Test 4 (IIII’10)   270  11-12/12  JKI/IOP   PNR      RPTD - RPTD
```

My Pattern: 
([\w ]+)\s+([\w()\’\’ ]+)\s+(\w+)\s+([\w/-]+)\s+([\w/+]+)\s+([\w.\s]+)\s+([\w -]+)

My Code:

```
Private Sub splitUpRegexPattern()
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String
Dim strInput As String
Dim strReplace As String
Dim Myrange As Range

Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A63")

For Each C In Myrange
    strPattern = "([\w ]+)\s+([\w\(\)\’\’ ]+)\s+(\w+)\s+([\w\/\-]+)\s+([\w\/\+]+)\s+([\w\.\s]+)\s+([\w \-]+)"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = C.Value
        'strReplace = "$1"

        With regEx
            .Global = False
            .MultiLine = False
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            C.Offset(0, 1) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$1")
            C.Offset(0, 2) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$2")
            C.Offset(0, 3) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$3")
            C.Offset(0, 4) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$4")
            C.Offset(0, 5) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$5")
            C.Offset(0, 6) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$6")
            C.Offset(0, 7) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$7")
            Else
            C.Offset(0, 1) = "(Not matched)"
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I need to group then as 
`Group1: (Test A1)  Group 2: ((III’15))   Group 3: (270) Group 4:   (10/12)   Group 5: (ABC/DEF)   Group 6: (PNR) Group 7:(AVC)`

Comment: Please provide the error that you received. Thanks

Comment: There is no Error Code it, just Sends Back Not Matched. In Regex101 it shows the grouping(using JavaScript), i expect it should return 1 group

Comment: I don't understand your pattern. What are you trying to match?

Comment: @Tom Group1: (Test A1)  Group 2: ((III’15))   Group 3: (270) Group 4:   (10/12)   Group 5: (ABC/DEF)   Group 6: (PNR) Group 7:(AVC)

Comment: Did you debug code to check which part is not working?

Comment: @EganWolf I used the same code for another Regex it worked fine, I think it has to do something with the Expression

Comment: How should the third data set split?

Comment: You Regex is not working for me... I tried to make a [demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/avekUJ/1), however, it is "ugly". The regex `([\w\s]*)\s*(\([\S\s]+?\))\s*([\w\d]+)\s*([\d|\-|/]+)\s*([\w|/]+)\s*(\w+\s?(?:\d|\.)*)\s*(\w+(?:\s?-\s\w+)?)`

Comment: Just checked your example and it's works "as is" without error with (not-so)proper replacing. [There](https://pastebin.com/8sbHUkE2) you can find the same code adopted to work with hard coded input, which was copied from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your pattern was off, and you also need to set `Global = True`.
This pattern will target each group of your strings. I haven't tested it with the `Replace` though as not sure what you were trying to achieve there.

[RegExr Fiddle](https://regexr.com/3hmb6)

**Updated with new pattern after comments:**

```
Private Sub splitUpRegexPattern()
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String, strInput As String, strReplace As String
    Dim j As Long
    Dim match
    Dim Myrange As Range

    Set Myrange = Range("A1:A63")

    strPattern = "(^.*(?=\())|(?:\().*(?:\))|((\d{2}(\/|\-)){1,2}\d{2})|(([a-z]{3}|[a-z]{1,2}\s[a-z]{1,2})(\/|(?!\/))){2}|((\w{2,4}(\s\-\s|$)){1,2})|((\w{2}\s)\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}|[a-z]{3})|((?!\)\s+)(([a-z]|[0-9]){3}))"
    If strPattern <> vbNullString Then
        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = False
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With
        For Each c In Myrange
            strInput = c.Value
            If regEx.test(strInput) Then
                j = 1
                For Each match In regEx.Execute(strInput)
                    c.Offset(0, j).Value2 = match
                    j = j + 1
                Next match
            Else
                c.Offset(0, 1) = "(Not matched)"
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you Help me out 
Test Asd(II’05) 300 11/12 RtF/Z XC PNR NKL 
Test 33 (I’01) PIL 11/12 K NP/IL O IL 90.5 FX - NO 
I was having trouble grouping (K NP/IL O), it needs to be in 1 group when I introduce a space ([\w]+ ) it detects as(RtF/Z XC PNR NKL).

Comment: @Ryan I've updated the code again. It should now detect these lines as well correctly. I've also updated the RegExr link - have a look at it to understand what the pattern is doing

Answer (score 1):

This will work assuming your spaces are real spaces and not character 160 as they are when copied from here:

```
Private Sub splitUpRegexPattern()
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String
Dim strInput As String
Dim strReplace As String
Dim Myrange As Range
Dim matches

Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A4")

For Each C In Myrange
strPattern = "([\w ]+)\s*(\([\w\’]+\))\s+(\w+)\s+([\w/-]+)\s+([\w/+]+)\s+(\w+\s?[\w.]*)\s+([\w -]+)"
    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = C.Value
        'strReplace = "$1"

        With regEx
            .Global = False
            .MultiLine = False
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            Set matches = regEx.Execute(strInput)
            C.Offset(0, 1) = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
            C.Offset(0, 2) = matches(0).SubMatches(1)
            C.Offset(0, 3) = matches(0).SubMatches(2)
            C.Offset(0, 4) = "'" & matches(0).SubMatches(3)
            C.Offset(0, 5) = matches(0).SubMatches(4)
            C.Offset(0, 6) = matches(0).SubMatches(5)
            C.Offset(0, 7) = matches(0).SubMatches(6)
            Else
            C.Offset(0, 1) = "(Not matched)"
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. It just returns `(Not matched)`

Comment: @Tom It was the Char160, on regex101 they were considered as spaces

Comment: @Tom Could you Help me out 

Test Asd(II’05) 300     11/12  RtF/Z XC      PNR        NKL
Test 33 (I’01) PIL     11/12    K NP/IL O      IL 90.5    FX - NO

I was having trouble grouping  (K NP/IL O), it needs to be in 1 group when I introduce a space ([\w]+ ) it detects everything after 
(RtF/Z XC      PNR        NKL).